Codeql Filter-SARIF Paths Not Ignored in Master Branch but Work in Other Branches
I'm using filter-sarif in my codeql yml file to ignore certain paths. This setup works perfectly in a feature branch where I initially added the ignore paths. However, after merging the changes into the master branch, the paths are not getting ignored.
Here’s what I’ve observed:

The codeql.yml file is present in master branch, with the correct paths listed for ignoring.
Running filter-sarif in the feature branch works as expected, and the specified paths are ignored in the SARIF output.
After merging into master, those same paths are not ignored.
Creating a new branch from master and running filter-sarif works as expected, with the paths being ignored.

Steps I’ve taken to troubleshoot:

Ensured the same version of filter-sarif is used in all branches.

Manually ran filter-sarif in the master branch without any errors or warnings.


Questions:

Why might filter-sarif ignore paths work in one branch but not in the master branch after merging?
Are there any known issues with filter-sarif when switching branches?
What additional steps can I take to debug this issue?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

suggest asking this on the a filter-sarif repo issue if that is indeed the tool you are mentioning here.

Run the upload artifact action in your workflow and then download/diff the two sarif files that are uploaded.
    - name: Upload loc as a Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: sarif-results
        path: sarif-results
        retention-days: 1

Is it excluding the alerts as expected?
